# how to trace the caret when typing in a contenteditable div on iOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari

I am developing a mobile website that contains a contenteditable div, within which, user may typing a long content.
the demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xJzXF/6/show/.
the source code on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xJzXF/6/.

the layout of my app is simple like bellow:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<div class="container">
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editor">this is contenteditable div</div>
</div>
```

If you visit the demo with android/chrome, it works well.
but if using iOS/safari, as the user typing into the div, the keyboard will cover what user is typing. iOS/safari seems not keeping the caret in the visible area. User must scroll to the cursor when typing, it's not acceptable.

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
thanks.

Comment: How did you deal with it eventually? I'm facing the same issue...